# How to get dependency component element by Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm creating a `React` component (`UserAutocomplete`) basing my `AutoComplete` component.

Where my `AutoComplete` component is:

```
render(
   <input type='text' class='autocomplete'/>
);
```

And my `UserAutoComplete` is:

```
import Autocomplete from './autocomplete';

render(
    <Autocomplete {...this.props} />
);
```

And creating test with `Enzyme` + `Jest`, but when I get `input` with `find` function, is returning `null`.

```
it('test defaultValue prop', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <UserAutocomplete/>
    );

    console.log(wrapper.find('input')); // returning null
});
```

How to can I get this input, if it's in child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) rendering does not render more that one level down (hence, *shallow*).  So, instead of `input`, you can search for the `AutoComplete` component:

```
it('test defaultValue prop', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <UserAutocomplete/>
    );

    console.log(wrapper.find('AutoComplete')); // returning null
});
```

If you want to render to more depth, you should use [mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) instead.